# Pandas: Select row pairs based on specific combination of strings in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm fairly new to python/pandas and have struggled to find an example specific enough for me to work with.

Say I have the following pandas dataframe, consisting of a column of event markers and a column displaying the time each marker was presented:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'Marker': ['S200', 'S4', 'S44', 'Tone', 'S200', 'S1', 'S44', 'Tone'], 
                    'Time': [0, 100, 150, 230, 300, 340, 380, 400]})

  Marker  Time
0   S200     0
1     S4   100
2    S44   150
3   Tone   230
4   S200   300
5     S1   340
6    S44   380
7   Tone   400
```

I would like to extract pairs of rows where S44 is followed by a Tone. The resulting output should be:

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame({'Marker': ['S44', 'Tone', 'S44', 'Tone'],
                   'Time': [150, 230, 380, 400]})

  Marker  Time
0    S44   150
1   Tone   230
2    S44   380
3   Tone   400
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

One way about it is to use shift to get the indexes, add 1 and pull with loc - note that this assumes that the index is numeric and monotonic increasing:

```
index = df.loc[df.Marker.shift(-1).eq('Tone') & (df.Marker.eq('S44'))].index

df.loc[index.union(index +1)]
 
  Marker  Time
2    S44   150
3   Tone   230
6    S44   380
7   Tone   400
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
s = ((df.Marker.eq('S44')) & (df.Marker.shift(-1).eq('Tone')))
df = df[s | s.shift()]
```

OUTPUT:

```
  Marker  Time
2    S44   150
3   Tone   230
6    S44   380
7   Tone   400
```